# How do I make a change to SQLNET and see the results?

Tags: oracle, timeout, sqlplus

I am having trouble changing settings on my SQLNET. I am running SQLPlus version 10.2.0.4. I thought all I needed was to open up the SQLNET.ora file, add a parameter, then save and restart the listener, and the change would be made. But none of the parameters are showing any effect.

Right now, just please advise, what is the simpliest thing I can change on SQLNET.ora that I can test is working or not working?

I have been focused on this parameter, thinking if I made the change correctly, the session would time out after a minute. But adding this change to both my SQLNET and the server's SQLNET seem to make no difference:
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 1

Comment: expire_time sends a keep alive signal, it isn't a timeout. To have your session time out, you'd need to set the connect_time limit in the session user's profile. That's not a listener thing. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Also be aware that 10.2.0.4 is ancient. It won't even connect to 19c and up, so you might want to update your software soon.